# Can I preview fixed size item inside layout in QtCreator?

Tags: c++, qt

So I have a `QDialog` and its set in Vertical layout. I am adding various line inputs and labels. On top I have one particular `QLabel` that loads `QPixmap` and displays image. Now even when I use `scaledContents(true)` the image tends to bloat up into its original size.

I cannot set geometry details as they are disabled in QtCreator for I am inside a Verical layout, so everything is scaled automatically.

I resorted to using `setFixedSize()` from `QDialog`'s constructor, but this doesnt give me correct preview in QtCreator.

How to set a fixed size inside layout in QtCreator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to select `Qt::KeepAspectRatio` for the `QPixmap` object within `QLabel`

For example:

```
QPixmap px;
QLabel label;
label->setPixmap(px.scaled(label->width(), label->height(),Qt::KeepAspectRatio));
```